# A possible timeout in find() method - mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a Node.js project using MongoDb and socket.io. I met one problem. I have a collection called rooms `rooms = db.collection('rooms');`
Here's my code when i'm trying to join a room

```
rooms.find({name: roomName}).limit(1).toArray()
   .then(function (res) { //if successful
       res = res[0]; //i get my username
```

If there's a room with the given `id` I connect to it, otherwise it must be created.

But when i create a new room i get `undefined`, but when I connect the second time (the room already exists) it's all ok, i get all the information. So when I create a room and connect to it, I don't get my username, but when it's created (I'm connecting to it the second time) it displays me the method.

`var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient` - module,

```
function http(io) { mongo.connect(config.mongodb_url) 
  .then(function (db) { ...
```

-connection,

`"mongodb version": "^2.1.7"`

This is how i create a room

```
rooms.findOneAndUpdate(
  {name: roomName},
  {$addToSet: {users: uuid}}
).then(users_update).catch(logger.error);
```

}).catch(logger.error);

I'm wondering if there are some timeout in the find method? Or where can be here the mistake?

Comment: What package are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: `var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient` - module, `function http(io) {
    mongo.connect(config.mongodb_url)
        .then(function (db) { ...` - connection, `"mogodb version": "^2.1.7"`

Comment: Show the code that creates the room.

Comment: @Tomalak, please - `rooms.findOneAndUpdate(
                        {name: roomName},
                        {$addToSet: {users: uuid}}
                    ).then(users_update).catch(logger.error);
                }).catch(logger.error);`

Comment: No, not in the comments. Put the whole thing into the question, in the proper context.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was just that simple: I added `{ upstream: true }` to my `findOneAndUpdate()` function.